# Falha ao ler arquivo .CSV

Tags: php, csv

Caros,tenho o seguinte codigo, onde leio um arquivo .CSV e mostro ele em uma tabela. Ele até faz o proposto, entretanto me retorna o erro `Notice: Undefined offset: 1` no final do arquivo. Isso para todas as matrizes, menos na 0

Como resolver esse erro?

```
<table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Usuário</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Perfil</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $linhas = fopen ("teste.csv", "r");

            while (!feof ($linhas))
            {

                $ponteiro = fgets($linhas, 4096);

                $valores = preg_split("[;]",$ponteiro);
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$valores[0]."</td>\n 
                      <td>".$valores[1]."</td>\n
                      <td>".$valores[2]."</td>\n
                      <td>".$valores[3]."</td>\n
                      <td>".$valores[4]."</td>\n
                      <td>".$valores[5]."</td>\n";
                echo "</tr>";     
              }

              fclose ($linhas);
              echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode tratar esse warning definindo um array padrão caso o resultado de `preg_split()` não seja o esperado. Basicamente verifique se é nulo e atribua o array padrão.

Outras alternativas para [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) são [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) e [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

```
$valores = preg_split("[;]",$ponteiro);

if(count($item) === 1 && is_array($item)){
   $valores = array_fill(0, 6, 'valor padrão');
}
```

Pode organizar melhor a forma gerar a tabela com um template e com a ajuda de [`vprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vprintf.php), ela recebe dois argumentos o primeiro é o template (string) com os placeholders (`%s`) e o segundo deve ser um array, o que a função faz é substituir os `%s` pelo repectivo elemento do array isso é feito de **forma posicional** ou seja o primeiro `%s` é substituido pelo valor do primeiro elemento do array.

No final seu código fica:

```
$template = '<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>';

while(!feof($linhas)){
   $valores = preg_split("[;]",$ponteiro);

   if(count($valores) === 1 && is_array($valores)){
      $valores = array_fill(0, 6, 'valor padrão');
   }
   vprintf($template, $valores);
}
```

Comment: Entendo que é necessário validar se ele esta nulo, estava validando através do isset(), entretanto sem sucesso tambem. Com essa solução proposta por você não tive efetividade tambem...

Comment: @WillianLima editei a resposta, esqueci que se não for encontrado o delimitador na string, ela é retornada mesmo assim e não como `false`.

Comment: Desta ultima forma, funcionou, a ultima linha ficou demarcada como 0. Ainda não é o ideal, mas ja é um começo haha. Obrigado

Edit: Realizei uma alteração no codigo, ficou perfeito agora!